# Deserializing a List of a:anyType

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have an existing XML file provided by another application, that looks similar to this:

```
<Root xmlns="http://someNameSpace">
    <DisplayName>RootName</DisplayName>
    <Groups>
        <Group>
            <Elements>
                <a:anyType i:type="SomeType">
                    <DisplayName>ElementName</DisplayName>
                </a>
            </Elements>
        </Group>
    </Groups>
</Root>
```

I'm attempting to write a class that can be deserialized with `XmlSerializer`, which currently looks like this:

```
public class Root
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group : SomeType
{
    public List<SomeType> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class SomeType
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

And simple deserialization code using `XmlSerializer`:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Root));
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(somePathToXmlFile))
{
    root = (Root) serializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
}
```

Everything is deserializing ok, except for the `Elements` list - it is always empty. I've tried adorning the `Elements` property in `Group` with `XmlAttributes` in the following ways:

1. `[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "a")]`
2. `[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "a:anyType")]`
3. `[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "a", Type = typeof(SomeType))]`
4. `[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "a:anyType", Type = typeof(SomeType))]`

So far, nothing has worked.

Does anyone know the correct way to get the `<a:anyType i:type="SomeType">` items to deserialize into the `Elements` list?

**Edit**
I've since realised I left out of my question was that the `<Root>` actually had a namespace: `<Root xmlns="http://someNameSpace">`. See XML above.

Comment: I just realised I mentioned Array in the title, but List in the code: I'm actually using List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts to get `XmlSerializer` to work I ended up changing to `DataContractSerializer`, which was used to do the serialization in the first place.

After implementing `DataContractSerializer` I had to provide an interface `ISomeType`, and update `Elements` to be a list of `ISomeType` rather than `SomeType`, to match the `<a:anyType i:type="SomeType">` XML elements

The final class structure looks like:

```
public namespace Project
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://someNameSpace")]
    public class Root
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://someNameSpace")]
    public class Group : ISomeType
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<ISomeType> Elements { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://someNameSpace")]
    public class SomeType : ISomeType
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ISomeType
    {
        string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the deserialization code:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(somePathToXmlFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fileStream, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()))
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (Root));
        var root = (Root) serializer.ReadObject(reader, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you xml with added namespace declartions on Root

```
<Root xmlns:a="http://custom/a" xmlns:i="http://custom/i">
<DisplayName>RootName</DisplayName>
<Groups>
    <Group>
        <Elements>
          <a:anyType i:type="SomeType">
            <DisplayName>ElementName</DisplayName>
          </a:anyType>           
        </Elements>
    </Group>
</Groups>
</Root>
```

I've succeeded in deserializing it using following xml attributes:

```
public class Group : SomeType
{

    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(SomeType),ElementName = "anyType", Namespace = "http://custom/a")]
    public List<SomeType> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class SomeType
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(string),ElementName="DisplayName",Namespace="")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you cannot add namespace declarations to xml use XmlNamespaceManager

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
        var nameTable = new NameTable();
        var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("a", "http://custom/a");
        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("i", "http://custom/i");
        var parserContext = new XmlParserContext(null, namespaceManager, null, XmlSpace.None);
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings()
        {
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment

        };
        using(var fileStream=File.OpenRead(somePathToXmlFile))
        {
            using(var reader=XmlReader.Create(fileStream,settings,parserContext))
            {
                var root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, that didn't seem to work in my case. I ended up using DataContractSerializer.